# Young diagrams for block matrices

Tags: permutations, representation-theory, symmetric-groups

Let $S_n$ be the group of permutations of $n$ elements. Consider the map $S_n \to S_{mn}$ of block permutations, and an irreducible representation of $S_{mn}$ (over the complex numbers), corresponding to a Young diagram $Y$. Naturally, it decomposes into a direct sum of irreducible representations for $S_n$. Is it possible to give a formula for this decomposition?

Block permutations: Consider $S_n$ as matrices in $\mathrm{GL}(n)$, embed $\mathrm{GL}(n)$ into $\mathrm{GL}(mn)$ as block matrices with scalar blocks of size $m \times m$, then you got the embedding $S_n \to S_{mn}$.

Comment: Your question is going to be closed because people cannot stand formulas without the surrounding `$`s, it triggers in them fears of the past.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *block permutations*?

Comment: Used Mathjax for math formulae, it is essentially TeX, which you know how to use.

Comment: And your map of permutation groups is unclear: Are you asking for an arbitrary homomorphism or a specific one?

Comment: Specific one. Consider S_n embedded in GL(n). Embed GL(n) into GL(mn) as block matrices with scalar blocks of size m*m. Then you got the desired map S_n -> S_mn

Comment: Do you have a guess? It seems like a natural enough embedding there could be an answer, but I haven't worked through any examples and I'm not sure I want to right now.

Comment: It seems, I do. Let \lambda and \mu be the irreducible reps for S_n and S_m. Consider induced representation from S_n x S_m to S_mn. It is irreducible. One has only to work out the respective Young diagram

Comment: Thank you, gentlemen, for your thoughts!